# Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date for property fromDate;

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-mvc, appfuse

I need to save Date type in this Format(dd/mm/yyyy) and currently this format works for me(mm/dd/yyyy)

**My jsp Code**

```
<form:input path="fromDate" id="fromDate" />
<form:errors path="fromDate"/>
```

I am using a script for date format as "format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'"

**Controller**

```
public ModelAndView saveOrUpdateAcademic(Academic academic,final BindingResult errors) {
String string = request.getParameter("fromDate");
System.out.println("========="+string+"=========");

try {
    if (validator != null) {
            validator.validate(academic, errors);
            if(errors.hasErrors()){
                saveError(request, getText("academic.error",academic.getAcademicYear(),locale));
                return new ModelAndView("admin/academicForm", model);   
            }
        }
 }
```

that string prints correct format as ("dd/mm/yyyy)

**Error :**

```
Failed to convert property value of type java.lang.String to required type java.util.Date for property fromDate; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not parse date: Unparseable date: "26/01/2015"
```

Please Help.

Comment: Could you include the Academic class code where you have the fromDate attribute?

Comment: @Column(name = "from_date") 
 @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
 @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
 @Field
 public Date getFromDate() {
  return fromDate;
 }
 public void setFromDate(Date fromDate) {
  this.fromDate = fromDate;
 }

Comment: You define pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" but you are using dd/MM/yyyy

Comment: I am using in Jsp Page only.   $('#fromDate').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
 });  it displays correct format as (14/01/2015) . I have a error in controller.

Comment: You need to change the pattern in your Academic class, from pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" to pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"

Comment: It throws same error

Comment: If you want to test which date is in your Academic fromDate attribute after you post to the controller, you may want to print academic.getFromDate() not make a request.getParameter

Comment: I print  academic.getFromDate()=Thu Apr 02 00:00:00 IST 2015 && request.getParameter("fromDate") = 04/02/2015

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateFormatter` in the method `initBinder` in your **Controller**:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.addCustomFormatter(new DateFormatter("dd/MM/yyyy","academic.fromDate" ));
}
```